# Confirmation that it is presently not possible to create a custom icon and use it in a lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

The [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) has an "Appending an Icon to Column Data" feature that allows an `iconName` to be taken from one of the data fields and the icon output to the left or right of the cell text. The example uses standard icons such as "utility:down" in its examples. This all works in the simple test I did.

I'd like to use some custom icons in a lightning:datatable but think this is not possible for these two reasons:

1. This [Lightning SVG Icon Component Helper](https://archive-2_1_4.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper) is no longer in the current documentation: is it correct that this approach no longer works (because of LockerService?) and that it is not possible to define a custom SVG icon?
2. The lightning:datatable `iconName` is not a general component reference but in fact "the Lightning Design System name of the icon" which is a set of names that cannot be added to?

Are these correct assumptions?

Comment: I think it depends on where you are using it.  If it is utilizing it as a button, therefore using the lightning:button, only utility icons are available.